# Enabling Sorting with Locked Rows in Excel

Tags: java, excel

Using java code, we are reading excel file template, filling data in rows, locking rows and finally generating file. With locked rows, its challenge to enable sorting. Apart from macro, is there any solution where we can enable sorting programmatically before generating file and having rows locked as well?